# Ubuntu on Asus ASUS X53E SX088V?

Tags: installation

I am new at Ubuntu. I put on my old HP Laptop for testing. I really like it and I would like to put it on my ASUS X53E SX088V. But it is not listed on the Ubuntu website of supportet Laptops. Is it really not possible to use Ubuntu on it? Where might be the risk?

Comment: Just prepare a ubuntu live cd/USB , plug in and boot in Live mode (Test mode).

Comment: As @Web-E suggested, try a Live CD or USB stick. If that works you should be able to install Ubuntu on the laptop, too.

Comment: A search for "Installing Ubuntu on an ASUS X53E" will likely get you to other users' experiences.

Answer (score 0):

i would say no problem, because you have a intel processor and the intel hd graphic.
this is all supported in ubuntu.

only problem you could have is wireless card won't work properly. it will work but not that good. you could try a live cd/dvd  or just make a bootable usb and select try ubuntu

I had the same with my asus laptop.                                                          my graphic card is a optimus card. which is not supported on linux. 
 [spec laptop](http://www.asus.com.au/Notebooks/Multimedia_Entertainment/N55SF/)

Comment: Some day I was installing Ubuntu on a friend’s laptop for engineering purposes. It was strange that Ubuntu didn’t detect wireless first while I was in live mode (no option even for enabling Wi-Fi), but as soon as I started the install procedure the internet was connected automatically! – just wanted to share.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Ubuntu, too, and have an Asus Q200 (which named itself X202E during the Ubuntu install - not sure what bit of hardware triggered that as they are very similar). But either way, neither of those models are Ubuntu certified either and my install works very nicely (I installed 12.10). I had to do a fresh install because the attempts with dual boot (I was going to leave Windows 8), were supremely frustrating.

I had to do a live USB install. And that worked like a charm.

Hope this helps - good luck!